# How can I add subtotal to table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum, case

Assume my table looks like the following:

```
id    count    sub_total
1     10       NULL
2     15       NULL
3     10       NULL
4     25       NULL
```

How can I update this table to look like the following?

```
id    count    sub_total
1     10       10
2     15       25
3     10       35
4     25       60
```

I can do this easy enough in the application layer. But I'd like to learn how to do it in MySQL. I've been trying lots of variations using `SUM(CASE WHEN...` and other groupings to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `id` field is sequential and growing then a correlated subquery is one way:

```
select *, (select sum(count) from t where t.id <= t1.id) 
from t t1
```

or as a join:

```
select t1.id, t1.count, sum(t2.count)
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.count
order by t1.id
```

To update your table (assuming the column `sub_total` already exists):

```
update t 
join (
  select t1.id, sum(t2.count) st
  from t t1
  join t t2 on t2.id <= t1.id
  group by t1.id
) t3 on t.id = t3.id
set t.sub_total = t3.st;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdc6b/1) showing the update.